Is there anyway to determine whether a dll is an ActiveX control or strictly a COM object?
I am currently working on a legacy project requiring me to identify ActiveX controls from a group of DLLs and OCXs. However, I find that the terms "COM" and "ActiveX" are almost interchangeable so finding the "difference" between them is confusing.
To my understanding, ActiveX controls are a type of COM object, so then must be something that differentiates a non-ActiveX COM object and an ActiveX COM object.
Is there anyway to see if a DLL contains an ActiveX control simply from looking at what interfaces it implements?
I've tried looking online, but the definitions are quite muddy and it seems there is no clear answer as to what is an ActiveX control vs what is a COM object.

Assuming you're willing to load the control into an application, you can use QueryInterface to see if the DLL implements IOleControl or IOleControlSite, as described below.  There's no way to tell just by looking.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/activex-controls-interfaces

To make it short, ActiveX was mostly a marketing term for COM.
ActiveX Controls are in general equipped with a type library, which is either embedded as a Win32 resource or provided as an external file (usually a .TLB file). A type library is not mandatory to work with COM but ActiveX controls where generally designed to support Internet Explorer and/or Visual Basic, MFC, etc.), languages or platforms that need some higher-level metadata to describe native objects and their methods.
You can visualize what a type library defines using the OleView tool from the Windows SDK.
For example, here is what it shows for the Remote Desktop Services ActiveX Client which is still provided today with Windows in mstscax.dll (run oleview mstscax.dll):

What you see in the (reconstructed) type library is the MsRdpClient2 coclass is an ActiveX control because it's marked with the control MIDL attribute.
So, what you can do is do the same as what OleView does, programmatically using the ITypeLib interface from LoadTypeLib and/or LoadRegTypeLib functions. A control will have the TYPEFLAG_FCONTROL, LIBFLAG_FCONTROL flags as documented in the control documententation.
